# Using my FacebookAppID did not work in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to use Facebook Api to get Facebook friends list. So, I create new app on [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/) and got AppID and give Bundle ID when I use that AppID and Bundle ID in my native iOS app and use api to get all friends list it get empty friend list.

And if I use the App ID of ["SendRequestHowTo"](https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.5-howtos/tree/master/SendRequestsHowTo) sample project it get all friend list of login user. Tell me how to configure my new app on Facebook Developer site to get friend list.

My code for get friends list:

```
// Query to fetch the active user's friends, limit to 25.
    NSString *query =
    @"SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN "
    @"(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";
    // Set up the query parameter
    NSDictionary *queryParam = @{ @"q": query };
    // Make the API request that uses FQL
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                                 parameters:queryParam
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error) {
                              if (error) {
                                  NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                              } else {
                                  _friends_list = (NSArray *) result[@"data"];
                                  NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);

                                  [self getLetsWalkeeFriendList];

                                  // Sort Table Data
                                  [self sortTableView];
//                                  [_tbl_view_friends reloadData];
                              }
                              [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
//                              [self.view hideToastActivity];
                          }];
```

Using Sample project AppID (i.e FacebookAppID: 403223126407920 and Bundle identifer: com.facebook.samples.SendRequestsHowTo). When I login with facebook I got output

```
Result: {
    data =     (
                {
            name = "Assad Sarwar";
            "pic_square" = "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpa1/t1.0-1/c153.5.545.545/s50x50/1978738_766566543368250_230425531_n.jpg";
            uid = 100000447351759;
        },
                {
            name = "Muhammad Hassan Butt";
            "pic_square" = "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xap1/t1.0-1/c0.0.50.50/p50x50/10167970_873047696055100_7845811348955741805_n.jpg";
            uid = 100000496339789;
        },
                {
            name = "Umair Jafar";
            "pic_square" = "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfp1/t1.0-1/c0.2.50.50/p50x50/10500337_910092152350902_4827832642500691993_n.jpg";
            uid = 100000503784242;
        }, .........
)
}
```

and when I used my AppID which is provided by facebook and using same user for login to facebook, I got output like

```
 Result: {
            data =     ( )
    }
```

Comment: go to developer.facebook.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For apps created after April 30th 2014, the endpoint `/me/friends` will only return a list of friends that also use your app. See the Platform Upgrade Guide [1].

[1] https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

Comment: I know how to use Facebook API but it give me response of friends list when I use [sample project](https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.5-howtos/tree/master/SendRequestsHowTo) AppID (i.e FacebookAppID: 403223126407920 and Bundle identifer: com.facebook.samples.SendRequestsHowTo). When I use my created app on developer.facebook.com AppID and Bundle identifier it didnot give me response of friends list. Kindly give me solution of that problem to use my AppID and Bundle  Identifier. Thanks in advance.

Comment: My answer is based on the small amount of information you provided. Add relevant code examples, error messages and log output and I am happy to help

Comment: I edit my question can you plz check this and give me solution.Thankx

Comment: I am pretty sure that the sample app has been created before the 30th of April 2014 and is still allowed to use v1.0 of the Graph API and that is the reason why it returns the friend list. When your app has been created after the 30th it is locked to v2.0. That means you need to request the user_friends permission and it will only return a list of friends that already use your app.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Change their permission for access Friend list. so you need to ask permission for that please visit this link and ask permission :- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/creating-ios-simulator-build-for-review

Comment: So, Can you plz tell me that I have to make simulator build for Facebook Review after that I got permission?

Comment: Go to your facebook developer account select your app. then go into status & review then go add item to this submission in this you can see all facebook permission select which you need then fill all information and submitt it

Comment: Yes you need to give simulator build then facebook give you permission.

Comment: Yes, I select my needed facebook permissions. And you said If i submit my simulator build for facebook review.Can facebook grant me that permissions? because I came to solution which is mention in (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1502515636638396/)